# RestEase client when deserialize IEnumerable<BaseType> ignores TypeConverter attribute specified on BaseType

Tags: api, rest, azure-devops, deserialization

I'm trying to use Azure DevOps API endpoint with RestEase.

I have interface

```cs
    public interface IEnvironmentClient
    {
                [Get("https://dev.azure.com/{organisationName}/{projectName}/_apis/pipelines/checks/configurations/?resourceType=environment&resourceid={resourceId}&$expand=settings")]
        Task<IEnumerable<EnvironmentCheck>> GetChecks([Path] string organisationName, [Path] string projectName, [Path] long resourceId, CancellationToken cancellationToken);

    }
```

```cs
    [TypeConverter(typeof (FooConverter))]
    public class EnvironmentCheck
    {
        public IdentityRef CreatedBy { get; set; } = new IdentityRef();
        public DateTimeOffset CreatedOn { get; set; }
        public IdentityRef ModifiedBy { get; set; } = new IdentityRef();
        public DateTimeOffset ModifiedOn { get; set; }

        public int Timeout { get; set; }
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public CheckType Type { get; set; } = new CheckType();
        public EnvironmentResource Resource { get; set; } = new EnvironmentResource();


    }

    [TypeConverter(typeof(FooConverter))]
    public class ApprovalCheck : EnvironmentCheck
    {
        public ApprovalSettings Settings { get; set; } = new ApprovalSettings();
    }
}
```

When I'm calling GetChecks the FooConverter is not working. Is there a way to make it work?

I could go using https://github.com/canton7/RestEase#custom-jsonserializersettings but really I don't like this as it complicates container registrations.

Comment: RestEase uses Json.NET for deserialization. I don't know whether Json.NET can be configured to use a TypeConverter

Answer (score 0):

The problem was just because I was using TypeConverter once I specified JsonConverter all started to work correctly.